# Let $\mathcal R$ be an open box. Suppose $\mathcal K$ is compact. Show $\mathcal K \subset \times_{i=1}^n [c_i, d_i] \subset \mathcal R$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $\mathcal R \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open box, that is $\mathcal R = \times_{i=1}^n (a_i, b_i)$ with $-\infty \le a_i < b_i \le \infty$.

Suppose $\mathcal K$ is a compact set with $\mathcal K \subset \mathcal R$.

I want to show the existence of $c_i, d_i$ such that $a_i < c_i < d_i < b_i$ and $\mathcal K \subset \times_{i=1}^n [c_i, d_i] \subset \mathcal R$.

I've shown that the projections $p_i : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ are continuous.

However, I cannot seem to find a rigorous argument regarding why these $c_i, d_i$ exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to define $[c_i, d_i] = p_i (K)$.

Comment: There is no reason for $p_i(K)$ to be connected. However, it will be contained in such an interval, which is what you want.

Comment: You are right! OP should be aware of this.

Comment: How do I use that fact that $p_i$ is continuous ?

Comment: $K$ is compact, $p_i$ is continuous, so $p_i(K)$ has a maximum and a minimum.